# Implement message delivery status in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to implement the ’sent’ status using `JSQMessagesViewController`

I have a message queue and a Chat view controller. When the message queue sends a particular message successfully I want to be able to reload a particular cell in the ChatViewController.

**How do I do this kind of communication between the message queue and the ChatVC?**

Here is what I have been able to do -

This is my message queue -

```
var unsentMessages = [String]() {
    didSet {
        // Check if a new value is being added or removed
        // If a new value is added then the oldValue will anve less elements than the original unsentMessages list
        if oldValue.count < unsentMessages.count {


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

                newValue in

                let messageID = unsentMessages.last


                let realm = try! Realm()


                for i in 1...10 {

                    if channel.subscribed {

                        let message = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Message.self, key: messageID)
                        channel.trigger("client-message", data: (message?.pusherMessage())!)
                        unsentMessages.popLast()

                        break

                    } else {

                        let time = 2 << UInt(i)
                        sleep(UInt32(time))
                    }
                }

            })
```

Now what i need to do is call the following code - `self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths()` from somewhere inside the ChatViewController. This is automatically reload the message cell and update the status.

**How can I invoke code inside the ChatViewController and pass data (the messageID) from the message queue.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just call `reload()` on your chatVC once the message sent is successful.